# Looking for a 64bit version of 32bit equivalent of WmiObject

Tags: powershell-3.0

I was trying to find a equivalent for the 64bit version for the "win32_computersystem" Get-WmiObject and its properties?  I have been looking but can not find it.  Any suggestions would be appreciated..

```
function GetStatus ($system = $_.name) {
        $userlogon = $null
        $userlogon= gwmi -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName $system | select -ExpandProperty username -ErrorAction Stop
        }
```

Thanks,

Mikey

Comment: What would you expect the "64bit version for the `win32_computersystem`" to be? The prefix `Win32_` is mostly historic and does not mean it is not usable in a 64bit process (eg. compare the results of your code in 32 and 64bit PowerShell instances).

Answer (score 2):

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390789.aspx :

```
Generally, provider writers do not include both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of a
provider in the same operating system. If no 64-bit provider exists, a 32-bit provider 
can continue to run through the facilities of WOW64
```

Then you can use `win32_computersystem` in a x64 OS.

[Here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/6062bbfc-53bf-4f92-994d-08f18c8324c0) you can find a usefull script to retrieve original (not wow64) registry value of a x64 OS remotely from a x32 OS.